# Interactive console/Pydev console breaks completely on unhandled error

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Eclipse Neon (4.6) with PyDev 5.1.2.

Run any python script with Pydev, break on something, and start playing in the normal console or the Pydev Debug console associated with the running script.

If you cause an exception, e.g. type 'test' (without the quotes) to reference a non-existent variable, after the traceback is printed, the console is unusable - you give it a statement, it thinks for a bit and then returns with no result.

In the Eclipse status bar it says 'PyDev Debug Console...Communication' (middle part is omitted, can't get that part of the UI to be long enough to see), but nothing else - i.e. it looks like the debugger dies when the exception happens.

I have used Pydev on and off for years, this is not a new thing for me but it is time I ask about it - is this normal behaviour?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by creating a new workspace, installing the usual plugins and configuring as normal - suddenly the ipython session can cope with errors it raises.